# Runtime error 1004:covariance inverse matrix

Tags: html, .net

A little new here! I am trying to calculate the Mahalanobis distance between 2 vectors, for which I need to calculate the covariance matrix between 2 vectors.
I have the following code to do this: basically the vectors are row vectors of size 1x8..these are stored in the variables x1 and x2. A difference of these 2 is then taken and stored in diff.
There is a separate function to calculate the covariance matrix and this is stored in covar1. 
However when I execute this, I get a runtime error 1004 on the line calculating the inverse of the covariance matrix:

covarinv = WorksheetFunction.MInverse(covar1)

Any help on this would be immensely appreciated!
Thank you.

```
Sub calculat()

Dim x1() As Variant
Dim x2() As Variant
Dim diff() As Variant
Dim covar1 As Variant
Dim covarinv As Variant
Dim md() As Variant



x1 = Range("b3:i3")
x2 = Range("b4:i4")




n1 = UBound(x1, 1)
n2 = UBound(x1, 2)
m1 = UBound(x2, 1)
m2 = UBound(x2, 2)

ReDim diff(1 To n1, 1 To n2)
    For j = 1 To n1
    For i = 1 To n2
        diff(j, i) = x1(j, i) - x2(j, i)
    Next i
    Next j

covar1 = VarCov(Range("b3:i7"))

covarinv = WorksheetFunction.MInverse(covar1)

temp = WorksheetFunction.MMult(diff, covarinv)
difft = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(diff)
md = WorksheetFunction.MMult(temp, difft)

End Sub


Function VarCov(rng As Range) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim colnum As Integer
    Dim matrix() As Double

    colnum = rng.Columns.Count
    ReDim matrix(colnum - 1, colnum - 1)

    For i = 1 To colnum
        For j = 1 To colnum
            matrix(i - 1, j - 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.covar(rng.Columns(i),        rng.Columns(j))
        Next j
    Next i

    VarCov = matrix

End Function
```